# NSFetchedResultsController and user driven changes: Best approach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Still struggling with this one. I'm reading data from coredata and present it in a table view with a NSFetchedResultsController. Problem is, I want my user being able to edit everything at once: Reorder, rename textfields in the rows, delete rows and add new ones.

So far I've (almost!) got it smoothly working with escaping all NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods as soon as user driven changes occur:
i.e.:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if (self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) return;
```

As soon as the edit mode starts in my table view I set this property to YES. After reordering I refetch the whole fetch request and reload the table. I only stop suspending and set this property to NO if I add or delete an item:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Basically saves the textfield
        if (self.activeField && [self.activeField isFirstResponder]){
            [self.activeField resignFirstResponder];
        }
        self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = NO;
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        //Results in a strange delete button behaviour. If omitted the order should still be valid.
//        //Adjust the indices of the remaining entries
//        int i = 1;
//        for (MainCategory *fetchedResult in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
//        {
//            fetchedResult.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i++];
//        }
    }
}
```

And in my textfield did end editing method I have this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(textField.text != mainCategory.name){
        mainCategory.name = textField.text;
    }

    self.activeField = nil;
}
```

Now you can see my only problem at the moment: If I'm in let's say the textfield of the 3rd row and I'm deleting the 2nd row, sometimes (not always!) the row number 4 before the deletion and row number 3 now, takes the text of the textfield I was editing before. I guess this is because I set the main category name with the IndexPath. And probably the NSFetchedResultsController messes something up there...

Any idea why or what I could do? I thought about completely avoiding the NSFetchedResultsController delegate and just refetch all the time some changes occur..but this should basically be the same result as I have now and not really faster...so how should I do it?

EDIT:
FRC delegate methods

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) return;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if (self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) return;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if (self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) return;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if(self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) return;

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges
{
    _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = NO;
}

- (void)setSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext:(BOOL)suspend
{
    if (suspend) {
        _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges) withObject:0 afterDelay:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you reload the whole table or just the changed row on deletion?

Comment: I don't reload on deletion. But since suspend is NO, the NSFetchedResultsController makes that himself somehow...

Comment: Yeah, you don't show what the delegate method does, presumably a reload or a single row reload...

Comment: See edit, inserted my complete delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

The FRC is still offering you batch loading while scrolling, so even though you are abusing the delegate functionality it's still worthwhile keeping it.

Your issue is really the use of the tag when the edit completes. Really you should record the row index when an edit starts. And you need to be careful using the field tag if you aren't updating the whole table after edits because you could have multiple duplicate tags and wrong tags.

A solution would be a custom cell where the cell is the delegate of the field. When edited, the field notifies the cell and the cell notifies the controller. You can then actually get the information back from the cell and the index from the table view.

Comment: My cells are custom anyway. So this approach seems quite easy doable. However how does the textfield notifies the cell and the cell the controller? Any example?

Comment: The cell would be the delegate of the text field and you would create a new delegate relationship between the cell and the controller (could be done with a block if you want).

Comment: Hm so I'm creating my own protocol? And this will work since my cell always knows the correct index path?

Comment: The cell doesn't know the index path, the table does. The only way your cell would know is if you tell it and update every cell after insertion and deletion.

Comment: Ok I'll try to do this and come back if I'm struggling :-)

Comment: One more question: Where do I set my cell as textFieldDelegate? The cell doesn't have a viewDidLoad does it?

Comment: No, if coming from a NIB, `awakeFromNib`. If not, then after the text field is created.